# Sum all xml tag values?

Tags: python, elementtree

This code is supposed to sum the count of comments in this xml document.

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'

print 'Retrieving', url
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
print data
for line in data:
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)
    comments = tree.findall('comments')

    name = comments[0].find('comment').find('name').text
    count = comments[0].find('comment').find('count').text
    count = int(count)
    count = count + count
print count
```

But it only displays the number of comments on the first `comment` tag and then adds it to itself and then stops.

Here's the output. The top is the `xml` document and at the bottom there is the count(**194**, which is **97+97**, only the comments by **Romina**), which is incorrect. It should be the sum of all comments in the file, not just Romina's

How to get the sum of all the comments in the file?

```
Retrieving http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml
Retrieved 4189 characters
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<commentinfo>
  <note>This file contains the sample data for testing</note>

  <comments>
    <comment>
       <name>Romina</name>
       <count>97</count>
    </comment>
    <comment>
       <name>Laurie</name>
       <count>97</count>
    </comment>
    <comment>
       <name>Bayli</name>
       <count>90</count>
    </comment>
    <comment>
       <name>Siyona</name>
       <count>90</count>
    </comment>
    <comment>
       <name>Taisha</name>
       <count>88</count>
    </comment>
    <comment>
       <name>Ameelia</name>
       <count>87</count>
    </comment>
    <comment>
       <name>Alanda</name>
       <count>87</count>
    </comment>
    <comment>
       <name>Prasheeta</name>
       <count>80</count>
    </comment>
</commentinfo>

194
```

Comment: Working on testing some of my own code and noticed at the bottom, you don't end your comments tag before commentinfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the subtle changes.
Because `<comments>` contains several `<comment>` tags, we first need to find all of them ,only then we can iterate over them and find the `<count>` tag.

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'

uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
comments = tree.find('comments').findall('comment')
total_count = 0
for comment in comments:
    count = comment.find('count').text
    count = int(count)
    total_count += count
print total_count
>> 2553
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop logic is wrong. Instead of

```
for line in data:
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)
    comments = tree.findall('comments')


    name = comments[0].find('comment').find('name').text
    count = comments[0].find('comment').find('count').text
    count = int(count)
    count = count + count
```

You need

```
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
comments = tree.find('comments').findall('comment')

count = 0
for comment in comments:
    name = comment.find('name').text
    count += int(comment.find('count').text)
```